Change size of shape XML for excel XLSX
I want to change the size of a comment created for a Excel XLSX using XML.
First we are adding the comments, and then the shapes, this is the code generated for the shapes:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xml xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
     <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
      <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
     </o:shapelayout>
     <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t202" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="202" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe">
      <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
      <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
     </v:shapetype>
     <v:shape id="_x0000_s1025 " type="#_x0000_t202" style="size:auto;width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;margin-left:117pt;margin-top:172.5pt;z-index:1;visibility:hidden" fillcolor="#ffffe1" o:insetmode="auto">
      <v:fill color2="#ffffe1"/>
      <v:shadow on="t" color="black" obscured="t"/>
      <v:path o:connecttype="none"/>
      <v:textbox style="mso-direction-alt:auto">
       <div style="text-align:left"/>
      </v:textbox>
      <x:ClientData ObjectType="Note">
       <x:MoveWithCells/>
       <x:SizeWithCells/>
       <x:Anchor>2, 15, 11, 10, 4, 31, 15, 9</x:Anchor>
       <x:AutoFill>False</x:AutoFill>
       <x:Row>9 </x:Row>
       <x:Column>2 </x:Column>
      </x:ClientData>
     </v:shape>    
    </xml>

I'm trying to change the line:
style="size:auto;width:auto;height:auto;position:absolute;margin-left:117pt;margin-top:172.5pt;z-index:1;visibility:hidden" fillcolor="#ffffe1" o:insetmode="auto">
Deleting the size:auto, putting something in width and height, but nothing happens.
I've tried to add cx and cy, but doesnt work.
